# Drupal returning 404 on images when not prefixed with www

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm attempting to help a friend configure their drupal site on the latest Drupal 7 release. I am being returned 404 on some images but not others.

Works: 
http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/fs_pic_sm.jpg

Doesn't work: 
http://example.com/sites/default/files/fs_pic_sm.jpg

What are the configuration steps needed to serve both? I'm not familiar with Drupal so if there is pertinent information I have omitted please inform me and I'll update this question.

Comment: Is it only images giving a 404? You may find this article interesting: http://tips.webdesign10.com/drupal/canonical-urls-319.html

Answer (score 0):

This could be a server setting as www.example.com and example.com are considered two different sites (www is a subdomain).

Edit your .htaccesss file in your document root and uncomment the lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This way they are automatically redirected to www and should no longer see the 404.